# Code Error for Merged Cells

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I am new to this and need help resolving this problem. I am trying to use this code on excel to change a cell's color and text, but it will not work for merged cells. How do I make it work for merged cells?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("$C$17:$C$80")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target
    Case ""
        Target = "Priority 1"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "Priority 1"
        Target = "Priority 2"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case "Priority 2"
        Target = "Priority 3"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case Else
        Target = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure would be helpful if you described what "will not work" means.  Nothing happens?  Error message? (if so, where and on what line?).  As a guess, you probably need to loop through each cell in target, if target turns out to be multiple cells.

Comment: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: You didn't indicate what line was returning the error.  Again, most likely you are operating on multiple cells (a merged cell will be multiple cells), so you may need to cycle through each cell in target (or each cell in the intersection of target and your range).

Comment: Interesting one. Can you mention the code routine calling this sub either in comments or by editing the post. I am  not quite clear on this point though it works.

Comment: The error highlighted Case "". @RonRosenfeld.

Comment: @skkakkar I'm not sure what you mean, this is all new to me. Sorry.

Comment: Seems my assumptions were correct.  I'm glad that Portland Runner's code works for you.  Note it might fail if you had merged cells that were both within and outside of the range to be acted upon.  That shouldn't happen the way your worksheet is layed out, though.

Comment: I am interested in knowing your input sample. I do have same doubts as @Ron Rosenfield has mentioned. Since I have to deal a lot with merged cells in my working, I am curious to know various ways of doing a thing related to merged cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super close, just change one line: `Select Case Target` to `Select Case Target.Item(1)`

Full Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("$C$17:$C$80")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Item(1)
    Case ""
        Target = "Priority 1"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "Priority 1"
        Target = "Priority 2"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case "Priority 2"
        Target = "Priority 3"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case Else
        Target = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

---

Results:

You can see here that I have a merged area from C23 to C26

[image]

Comment: If I wanted to change the range to several selected cells, how would I do that? @PortlandRunner    `C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17,M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34,AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17,AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54,BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93`

Comment: You should be able to change the intersect range to include disjointed cells.  Here is the first three for example: `Range("C17,C21,C25")`

Comment: The code will not let me do that because there are too many characters.

Comment: I see two options: 1. Use a named range instead or, 2. Split up the intersect command into multiple logic statements.  I'd vote for the named range since it simplifies your code but it may be confusing for someone to modify in the future without a clear comment.